# Lost rankings after redirecting keyword page to home page, can I optimize my home page for that keyword?

Tags: seo, keywords, backlinks, homepage, link-building

I had been ranked for a desirable phrase in the past, but I redirected that page to the homepage. This was a bad mistake. Now my homepage isn't ranking in the search results nearly as well for that phrase.

I've tried to get some good back links to my homepage with this keyword, but it hasn't helped. All my competitors are ranked for this phrase by their internal page.

Do you think I should continue try to rank my homepage with this phrase or make a new internal page for this phrase? The homepage of my site is ranked first with my brand keyword but I would like to get it ranked for that phrase if possible.

Comment: Why did you want your home page to rank rather than the internal page?

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing that is not clear to me: why did you redirect the well positioned page to the homepage?
And does the homepage REALLY contain information about the keyword your are interested for?

A basic advice I can give is also the simplest: try to create a good website for your visitors first of all. The search engine will start to appreciate it too. And don't hurry.

PS: obviously it's useless and foregone to be at first position with the company name. If a person search your company name surely already knows you.